# Same JQuery code, different statusText values on different machines

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqxhr

I can't figure this one out for the life of me... I have the following simple div block:

```
<div id="result">Loading...</div>
```

and the following simple JQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  url: "/bogus-url",
  method: "GET",
  success: function(data) {
    $("#result").html(data);
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
    $("#result").html('Error occurred: ' + xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```

When I run it on one machine I get

```
Error occurred: 404 Not Found
```

and yet, when I run it another machine I get

```
Error occurred: 404 error
```

In fact I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PillowMetal/ftuj9m8v/5/) that demonstrates this. I'm curious which version you guys get when you run it. Does anyone know what would cause this difference in behavior?

Comment: The status code (404) defines the result, not the text.

Comment: Yes, but my question is why the same jQuery code returning the same status code would have different status text dependent on where it is run... what process determines the text that is placed in the statusText field?

Comment: The application on the server, the web server, the client browser, the library used for the request or any party (that has access to the http packets) in between that path...

Comment: In my case, the app, the web, and the library are identical because it's all under JSFiddle's control... the only difference is the Chrome browser version (updating is under group policy on one of my machines)... I will try to eliminate that remaining variable